# List within list

Tags: python

Python code should print [['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]

```
comb = list()
ingd = list()

class IceCreamMachine:

    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
    
    def scoops(self):
        for ingredient in self.ingredients:
            for topping in self.toppings:
                comb.append(ingredient)
                comb.append(topping)
           
            ingd.append(comb)       
            comb.clear()
    
        print(ingd)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
    print(machine.scoops())
```

But my code prints
[[], []]
None

Comment: The last line of your code prints the return value of `Machine.scoops()`. But that method has no `return` statement so the method returns `None`. There is also a `print()` call inside the method. But that prints `comb` after the previous line of code resets it to empty. Do `ingd.append(comb[:])` instead. And put the `print()` call *inside* the `ingredient` loop, otherwise it will print only the last value. And `comb` and `ingd` are local to the method so it would be less error-prone to define them inside it, rather that as global variables as you are doing.

Comment: @BoarGules I think this is too confusing as a comment. It would be better as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create lists inside your method:

```py
class IceCreamMachine:

    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
    
    def scoops(self):
        ingd = []
        for ingredient in self.ingredients:
            comb = []
            for topping in self.toppings:
                comb.append(ingredient)
                comb.append(topping)
           
            ingd.append(comb) 
        return ingd 
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
    print(machine.scoops())
```